# Appropriate post-hoc test for many comparisons following 2-way ANOVA

Tags: multiple-comparisons

A reviewer has suggested using either the Hochberg step up or Bonferroni step down analysis or similar tests to better control for Type I error by controlling the alpha value for the number of comparisons we are making. The statistical suite we are using does not have the above methods, but offers Holm-Sidak, which appears to perform a similar analysis. Would this be an appropriate analysis for 10-30 comparisons?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. That would be an appropriate way to control for the [family-wise error rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familywise_error_rate) (FWER). This method sacrifices far less statistical power than Dunn's Bonferroni adjustment.

In the Holm-Sidák adjustment, the FWER is controlled in steps by adjusting the $p$-values (adjusted $p$-values are sometimes termed $q$-values in the literature) of each pairwise test (ordered by $p$-value from smallest to largest) to be $1 - (1 - p)^{(m+1-i)}$, where $i$ indexes the order of unadjusted $p$-values. The Holm-Sidák procedure fails to reject all pairwise tests, starting with the first test for which adjust $p > \alpha/2$ (see Holm, 1979).

**References**
Holm, S. (1979). A simple sequentially rejective multiple test procedure. *Scandinavian Journal of Statistics*, 6(65-70):1979.